# how to minimize my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to minimize my query

```
 "SELECT * FROM tb_videos  GROUP BY DATE(added) ORDER BY DATE(added) desc"
```

after get result

```
foreach($result as $rst)
{    
  $dt=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($rst->added));
  SELECT * FROM tb_videos WHERE  DATE(added)='$dt' ORDER BY added desc
}
```

Can i do with single query?

Comment: What is the first query that gives you $result? Show us that, and we should be able to work out a join query to reduce the number of database queries you're executing

Comment: first query returns grouped dates

Comment: Telling us what it does won't help... we need to know the query itself. And we need to know what you're trying to achieve.... I assume this is related to your previous question

Comment: Can you explain us what are your criteria while fetching the rows and what type records you want to purchase from DB. PLease do modify your question in that sense

Answer (score 2):

Your queries make no sense. First you are selecting the DISTINCT dates (ignore time) from the data. Then for each date, you.. select all data for that date?

Why don't you just fire one query

```
SELECT *, DATE(added) as DateNoTime
FROM tb_videos
ORDER BY added desc
```

If you only want 5 dates, and the table is large, there are two possibilities.

1, There are never gaps in dates, you can use

```
SELECT *, DATE(added) as DateNoTime
FROM tb_videos
WHERE added >= ADDDATE(CURDATE(), interval -4 days)
ORDER BY added desc
```

2, If there may be gaps, e.g. nothing for yesterday so it has to show last 5 days that have records

```
SELECT *, DATE(added) as DateNoTime
FROM (
    select min(DateNoTime) as MinDate
    from
    (
        select DATE(added) as DateNoTime
        FROM tb_videos
        order by DateNoTime desc
        limit 5
    ) x) y, tb_videos
WHERE added >= y.MinDate
ORDER BY added desc
```

This gives you all the data. In PHP, keep track of DateNoTime. Whenever that changes, you are in a different date, which would have previously caused you to fire another query.  The code should otherwise only change minimally.

Unchecked PHP code

```
$result = mysql_query('
    SELECT *, DATE(added) as DateNoTime
    FROM (
        select min(DateNoTime) as MinDate
        from
        (
            select DATE(added) as DateNoTime
            FROM tb_videos
            order by DateNoTime desc
            limit 5
        ) x) y, tb_videos
    WHERE added >= y.MinDate
    ORDER BY added desc
');
$prevdate = NULL;
foreach($result as $rst)
{    
    if($prevdate!=$rst=>DateNoTime) {
        // do something, like printing out a header for each new date
        $prevdate=$rst=>DateNoTime;
    }

    // do something with the record
}
```

Comment: i hope it will help with me but i have another problem with it. If i use it,my pagination will collapse because i want to list 5 days videos per page

Comment: @Sammem you left out a LIMIT clause from the question

Comment: Really your code is very helpful. Now i have another problem with it please help me. I want to do pagination with it. If i use this,only i can list videos per page by no of videos but i want to list videos per no of days

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi thanks..I'm using codeigniter. so i want to implement this into my CI pagination. After 5 hrs hair fall i got an idea from you

Answer (score 1):

You want to minimise the records found? use a where clause to choose your specific records

"SELECT * FROM tb_videos WHERE videogroup = action GROUP BY DATE(added) ORDER BY DATE(added) desc"

For example

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tb_videos WHERE DATE(added) = curdate() ORDER BY added desc
```