# select DISTINCT dates from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to select the DISTINCT dates (ignore time) from the table; then for each date, I want to select all data for that date?

Comment: How many different user accounts do you need to ask this set of questions? And why can't you accept the advice and help given in your previous questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376322/how-to-minimize-my-query

Answer (score 0):

Don't execute a query for each date, rather you should do something like:

```
SELECT DATE(date_column), other_column FROM your_table ORDER BY DATE(date_column)
```

And when you are processing your result set pay attention to whether the date result has changed.

This way you only dispatch one query.

Comment: Good.wt can i do if i use pagination?..bcoz pagination usually depends query.